# Extract data from .jar file and show it in html table

Tags: html, jar, xampp

I'm new in this field. I have a **.jar** file and i want to show data of all users in .jar in my html table. I'm using **xampp**. Any type of help would be appreciated. Do let me know if i can do it in Php.

Comment: What type of data are you looking to extract from the jar?

Comment: users data stored in .jar file for login purpose and i want to see all the users data on a html page.